Copy a formula to all the sheets in Google Spreedsheets
I have a Google Spreedsheets with a lot of Sheets (more than 400)...and I need to insert formulas (H2:H13) in all the Sheets.
I know that I can do it manually..taking Sheets one by one.
I also tried this App Script, but this also means i need more than 400 App Scripts...
function Movedata1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var dstSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("H2:H13");
  var dstRange = dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() - 11, 8);
  srcRange.copyTo(dstRange); // or srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });
}

I would need some help with App Script to make it works for all the sheets.
The link for of the Spreedsheets is here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LR0i-2LCg6ZrfBGHpX-XVlScRgvcOxh1te9Wj_x7ObA/edit?gid=0#gid=0
THANKS!

Using getSheets() you can then loop thru all of the sheets, updating the formulas/values:
function Movedata3() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const allsheets = ss.getSheets();
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("H2:H13");
  allsheets.forEach((sheet) => {
    const dstRange = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() - 11, 8);
    srcRange.copyTo(dstRange); // or srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, { contentsOnly: true });
  });
}


You can do this to iterate through all sheets and copy formulas from H2:H13 to the cells in each sheet. Try this first in a test sheet.
function Movedata1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssName= "Sheet1";

  //get source sheet and range
  var srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName(ssName);
  var srcRange = srcSheet.getRange("H2:H13");
  
  //get all sheets in spreadsheet
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  
  // Loop through each sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var sheet = sheets[i];

    // Skip the source sheet to avoid overwriting
    if (sheet.getName() === ssName) continue;

    // Get the destination range based on last row
    var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    var dstRange = sheet.getRange(lastRow - 11, 8);

    // Copy formulas only (preserves formatting)
    srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMULA);
  }
}

Let me know if it worked!
